# Grep one file and remove contents of the grep with sed -i on a second file

Tags: sed, grep

I am trying to grep ip addresses from one file and remove the contents of the grep from a second file with a single command.

The masterfile has

```
header x.x.x.x
header x.x.x.x
header2 y.y.y.y
header2 y.y.y.y
header3 z.z.z.z
header3 z.z.z.z
```

The tempfile has

```
x.x.x.x
x.x.x.x
y.y.y.y
y.y.y.y
z.z.z.z
z.z.z.z
```

Attempt

```
grep "header" masterfile | sed 's/^.* //' | sed -i "" '/$/d' tempfile
```

Would also like to remove the empty line after the sed command removes an entry.

Comment: How shall the output look like?

Comment: the tempfile will be have all x.x.x.x removed as it was part of the "header" group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correct, you need the following:

```
grep -v -F -f <(grep '\<header\>' masterfile | cut -d' ' -f2) tempfile
```

or

```
grep -v -F -f <(sed 's/^header *//' masterfile) tempfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
y.y.y.y
y.y.y.y
z.z.z.z
z.z.z.z
```

In order to save the changes to `tempfile`, you could redirect the command output to another file and move it to the desired file:

```
grep -v -F -f <(sed 's/^header *//' masterfile) tempfile > tmp && mv tmp tempfile
```

---

EDIT: You seem to be `sh` which doesn't support Process Substitution.  In that case, you can use the following:

```
grep '\<header\>' master | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep -v -F -f - tempfile
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting a "Missing name for redirect." error with each of the three commands?

Comment: The shell is FreeBSD 8.3-RELEASE-p11

Comment: @CA171 I suppose that you changed the command, probably introduced a space after `<`.  Moreover, I presume that you are using `bash` and not `sh`.

Comment: It is sh. I tried with no space, space. Did some googlefu without any luck. Only way to get this to work is to grep/sed to a file and then use the grep -Fvf with the two individual files. If you know a workaround please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @CA171 Added an alternate solution in the answer that should work in `sh` too.

Answer (score 2):

Produce a `sed` script from the first file and feed it to a second `sed` instance.

```
sed 's%^header \(.*\)%/^\1\$/d%' masterfile |
sed -i "" -f - tempfile
```

On Linux, `-f -` says to read the script from standard input. On some other platforms, this does not work; then, you'll have to save the script to a temporary file (or maybe you have `/dev/fd/1` or `/dev/stdin`).