# How to replace a multiple values in a minified javascript file with sed

Tags: javascript, regex, bash, sed

I need to replace a couple values in a minified javascript file with sed. The OS is alpine Linux.

I'm trying to workout a generic regex which will find `foo:` and any characters until the next `,` like so: `foo:____`  and replace with `foo:"bar"` or `foo:!0` whatever the value in the variable might be. This script needs to work all the time. It shouldn't depend on was is coming after the `:` ( meaning whatever the value from the property is).

**Here are the first couple characters from the file**

```
(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[5],{3:function(l,n,t){l.exports=t("zUnb")},AytR:function(l,n,t){"use strict";t.d(n,"a",function(){return e});var e={appVersion:"1.4-beta",buildNr:"123.123",production:!0,tracking:!0,apiHost:"/api/",foo:""}},Cdxl:function(l,n,t){"use strict";t.d(n,"a",function(){return a});
```

**Here is my start it isn't generic at all  ...**

```
APP_VERSION='"1.4-beta"'
BUILD_NR='"20190118.1"'
PRODUCTION="!"
TRACKING="!0"
API_HOST='"/api/"'
FOO='"bar"'

# demo for the first 3 variables 
sed -i "s/appVersion:[\"0-9A-Za-z.]*/appVersion:${APP_VERSION}/;s/buildNr:[\"0-9A-Za-z.]*/buildNr:${BUILD_NR}/;s/production:[!0-9A-Za-z.]*/production:${PRODUCTION}/" path/to/js-file.js
```

I tried for hours - Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you want to match everything up to the next `,`, you can just use `[^,]*`

Comment: Cross-site duplicate with a much better solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476536/how-to-find-and-replace-multiple-field-values-using-jq

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `g` modifier on the end of the regex to replace *all* occurrences of pattern match.

#### General Example

```
{one:"1",two:"2",three:"3",one:"one",plz:"nope"}
```

I want to replace everything after `one` with `"42"`. Without the global modifier, I get this result:

```
$ sed -E 's/one:[^,]+/one:"42"/' foo.txt
{one:"42",two:"2",three:"3",one:"one",plz:"nope"}
```

Note how the second instance of `one:` has not changed. Now with the `g` modifier:

```
$ sed -E 's/one:[^,]+/one:"42"/g' foo.txt
{one:"42",two:"2",three:"3",one:"42",yas:"nope"}
```

That replaces all occurrences.

#### Your specific case

Stick this into a file, maybe called `replacer.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# declare `swap` to be an associative array
declare -A swap

swap[appVersion]='"1.4-beta"'
swap[buildNr]='"20190118.1"'
swap[production]="!"
swap[tracking]="!0"
swap[apiHost]='"\/api-2\/"'
swap[foo]='"bar"'

FILE=$1

for key in ${!swap[@]}; do sed -E -i 'bak' "s/${key}:[^,]+/${key}:${swap[${key}]}/g" $FILE; done
```

Change the keys and values in the `swap` variable to be what you need. Case matters, and escape any backslashes in the values.

If you need to replace more things, you can simply add more key/value pairs. The loop will iterate over all keys, applying the changes in order.

`sed` can automatically create backup files with the `-i` flag; I think these might get blown away during each iteration of the loop—be careful here.

Run program like so: `$ ./replacer.sh filename.js`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looping over a file multiple times to do `sed -i` on each iteration is an antipattern. You want to feed `sed` a more complex script which performs all the substitutions you want, and only process the file once.

Comment: More fundamentally, the real problem here is that `sed` is not a good tool for implementing a completely general JSON parser. A correct script should understand when JSON occurs quoted inside a JSON string, for example.

Comment: @tripleee You are definitely correct about the JSON parsing—Your answer is much better. Stevo asked specifically about sed however. Thanks for the point about repeated uses of `sed -i`! I’m no Bash expert, and I’m glad to learn. :)

Comment: Something like this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22746932/874188